# Error parsing arguments to execvp in my custom linux C Shell

Tags: c, shell, execvp

So I am trying to create my own C custom shell for Ubuntu as part of a bigger homework project. I am using the function MyArguments to tokenize user input using strtok with spaces as the seperator, note that there's no need to check the credibility of user input. The Function MyArguments SEEMS to be tokenizing user input seperated by spaces correctly, at least they appear as they should be when I printf them, however when it is time to execute the actual command, and I parse something like "/bin/ls -l" I get an error message like this:

/bin/ls: invalid option -- '
'

Any idea at what could the problem possibly be? My guesses on the matter are

1) I use execvp, the first argument, is/should be the first token from the input, for our example above it is "/bin/ls", so far so good, however for the command arguments I use the whole array of the tokenized input, {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL}, the problem being is it should be something like {"-l', NULL}

2) My tokenized input is not actually {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL} but something more like
{"/bin/ls", "-l", "                           ", NULL} because my fgets reads command line input of 40 characters length, fills the string with " "'s until it reaches the 40 character point, and then at some point, something like "                      " is parsed as an argument to execvp which doesn't recognize it as a valid command argument.

Any help/tips would be welcome.

```
char** MyArguments(char* s);
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    int fd[2];
    char** tokenized;
    char* input = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    printf("MyShell2:> ");
    pid_t pid;
    while (!feof(stdin)){
        pipe (fd);
        fgets(input, 40, stdin);
        tokenized = MyArguments (input);
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
            printf("Error creating child\n");
        }
        else if (pid == 0){
            close (fd[1]);
            read (fd[0], tokenized, sizeof(tokenized));
            close (fd[0]);
            execvp(tokenized[0], tokenized);
        }
        else{
            close (fd[0]);
            write (fd[1], tokenized, sizeof(tokenized));
            waitpid (pid, NULL, 0);
            close (fd[1]);
        }
        printf("MyShell2:> ");
    }
    free (input);
    free (tokenized);
    return 0;
}

char** MyArguments(char* s){
    char** arguments;
    char* result ;
    int count =0;
    arguments = calloc(1, sizeof (char *));
    result = strtok(s, " ");
    while(result !=NULL ){
        arguments[count] =result ;
        ++count;
        arguments = realloc(arguments, sizeof(char*)*(count + 1));
        result=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    arguments[count] = NULL;
    return arguments;
}
```

Comment: I hope this isn't your actual code, and in your actual code you check for errors. All of the system calls you make can return with errors that you need to check for.

Comment: Also, don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect. The reason is that the `EOF` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. This leads you to loop one time extra without you noticing you're already at the end of the file. Instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`

Comment: And a third thing, why send the pointer to `tokenized` through a pipe to the child process? Remember that `forks` duplicates the *complete* process, including all memory allocated on the heap *and* variables (like the `tokenized` pointer).

Comment: And a couple of tips in helping you debut your problem: A simple way is to print out things, like all the strings in the `tokenized` array. But the best way is to use a *debugger*, then you can stop at specific places in the code, you can then examine variables and their values, you can step through the code line by line. Learning to use a debugger is (in my opinion) a requirement to become a good programmer.

Comment: And finally, read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), it doesn't work the way you think it does in the second point. It *does* however leave the newline in the input.

Comment: Well thanks for your effort and the extensive tips, and yes there was no reason to pipe anything to the child, long story short, I ditched fgets() for getline() adding a '\0' to the end of the user input and it seems to work just fine now.